# A recurrence relation for Stirling numbers (2nd kind)

Tags: recurrence-relations, summation, stirling-numbers

It is well-known that the Stirling numbers of the second kind satisfy the following (vertical) recurrence relation:

$$\sum\limits_{r=k}^n \binom{n}{r}S\left(  r,k\right) =S\left(  n+1,k+1\right) $$

I was wondering if the following sum satisfies a similar relation:

$$\sum\limits_{r=k}^n a^{r} \binom{n}{r}S\left(  r,k\right)=f(a,r,k) S\left(  n+1,k+1\right),\ \ \ \ 0<a\leq1   $$

I came across this sum when trying to implement the Stirling numbers in an economics model (I'm not a mathematician). I have already had a look at several papers regarding Stirling numbers and Chapter 8 ("Stirling numbers") in "Enumerative Combinatorics" (Charalambides), but without success.

Any help/useful references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Such equations are easier to read as displayed equations, which you get by enclosing them in double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Reading through the chapter in Enumerative Combinatorics again, I was wondering if the answer to my question might be related to "generalized factorial coefficients"?

Comment: I asked a question about the same sum [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/251703/2370).  There are lots of different results about this sum in the question and answers there.